# Run time error 1004 copy and pasting accross worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to combine data from two worksheets into a single worksheet.

The "PUF" worksheet contains a larger dataset, with all cases sorted by "ID".
A smaller subset of these case IDs, contain additional data in a second worksheet called "ADHD".

My goal is to copy the additional data in the smaller "ADHD" worksheet, and paste it adjacent to data in the "PUF" worksheet. The IDs must match.

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
Sub copypuf()

For x = 2 To 2967

'get ID number of case in ADHD worksheet

Dim y As Long

y = Worksheets("ADHD").Cells(x, 1).Value

y = y + 1

'Copy cells from from ADHD worksheet, into the respective ID number on original data sheet

Worksheets("ADHD").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 261)).Copy Worksheets("PUF").Range(Cells(y, 368), Cells(y, 628))

Next x

End Sub
```

> The error message that I get is "runtime error 1004; application-defined or object defined error"
>
> Please help I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells()` with the worksheet just as you did for `Range()`.  "Free-standing" `Cells()` in a regular code module always refers to the ActiveSheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub copypuf()
    Dim y As Long

    For x = 2 To 2967

        y = Worksheets("ADHD").Cells(x, 1).Value + 1

        Worksheets("ADHD").Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 261).Copy _   
                            Worksheets("PUF").Cells(y, 368)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not do at all what the OP asked for. @devakotia I have modified my code completely after testing and it should do exactly what you asked for so long as I have interpreted what you are wanting correctly.

Comment: @ClintStreet - perhaps you can explain how you think it deviates from the requirements ?

Comment: From the question "My goal is to copy the additional data in the smaller "ADHD" worksheet, and paste it adjacent to data in the "PUF" worksheet. The IDs must match."

Comment: As long as the PUF sheet contains a continuous sorted list of ID numbers (starting from 1 in the second row) then why wouldn't this code work? I took my lead from the code posted by the OP...

Comment: Yes assuming that it is a continuous list that is sorted it would work. The op mentioned that they were inexperienced and needed help so I figured the code was not matching what the op requested. Why would he mention the ID's must match then. It is poorly stated question then since the ids would not matter if it was two identical sorted lists.

Comment: Yes, it is a continuous list that is sorted. Sorry that I did not mention this assumption. I should be more clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you use the range object by creating Range object variables and assigning them to your worksheet ranges where you want your data to go.

```
 Sub copypuf()
  Dim x As Long
  Dim r1 As Range 'range for smaller dataset
  Dim r2 As Range 'range for larger dataset
  Dim r4 As Range 'range to check if find is a success
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim y As Long
 Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADHD") 'smaller dataset copy to the below larger dataset
 Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PUF") 'larger dataset get values from above offset
y = 1

 Dim idNum As Variant

 With ws1
    Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2967, 261)) 'ADHD range
 End With

For x = 1 To r1.Rows.Count

    idNum = r1.Item(x, 1).Value 'get ID number in ADHD worksheet

    y = y + 1

With ws2
    Set r2 = .Range(.Cells(y, 368), .Cells(y, 628)) 'PUF range
End With

 'Copy cells from from ADHD worksheet, into the respective ID number on       original data sheet
With r1 ''copy the cells from the range
    Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, .Columns.Count)).Copy
End With

Set r4 = r2.Find(idNum) 'Find the next id number if it is not found nothing is returned

If Not r4 Is Nothing Then
    With r2
        .Offset(0, .Columns.Count).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End With
 End If
    Set r2 = Nothing
    Set r4 = Nothing
Next x
Set r1 = Nothing
Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @Devakotia did you get a chance to try this out? I have corrected the mistake Davesexcel mentioned.

Comment: What is `y` starting as?

Comment: y is starting as "idNum", and y+1 is to account for the first row which a header that has the variable names.